# List option values fail to insert into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a php form to insert values into a database.
One of my form options is a dynamic list populated with fields from another table.
I first created the form without the dynamic option, and all data inserted just fine (and still does).
Now I'm attempting to include the code below, and while it displays the option values properly, the value fails to insert.  Any advice?

```
        <?php
/*
 * LIST ALL CATEGORIES
 ****************************************/
 include('../dbconnection.php');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ingredient_categories';
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<select>';
while ($ingredientCategoryOption = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$ingredientCategoryOption[category_id].'">'.$ingredientCategoryOption[category_name].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: your select has no `name` attribute

Comment: I don't see any sql query for data insertion.

Comment: the insert query is on the add_ingredient.php page (which has the form).  the above code was just included on that page.

Comment: @phgdanny I wrote some similar code as yours yesterday. The $polls array is passed to the `view` in `CodeIgniter` in the `$this->load->view('poll.php', $data['polls'])`, while you do it in the page itself. I posted my answer, please check it out, and if it solve your problem, please accept it so other people can use it as base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created something similar yesterday. The `$polls` array is passed to the view in `CodeIgniter` in the `$this->load->view('poll.php', $data['polls'])`, while you do it in the page itself. However, you can have the general idea.

```
<FORM id="formPoll" class="question" name="createpoll" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/poll/selectOption/" method="POST">
     <select name="poll_list">
        <?php
        foreach($polls as $poll){
            echo "<option name='poll_table'>$poll->name</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
     <div id="input">
        Poll name: <input type="text" name="name"></input>
        Title: <input type="text" name="title"></input>
     </div>
     <div id="options">
        Option: <input type="text" name="option"></input>
     </div>

     <input type="submit"></input>
</FORM>
```

Some ideas:

1. Check if `$results` is not empty before using it
2. Give your `<select>` form a name, as I showed above
3. Check if `$ingredientCategoryOption` is not `null` or is something returned.
4. Check your database connection

Comment: yup...it was 1) my dumbass not adding the name 2) my dumbass using _id instead of _name in the option value, lol.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: i hit "yes" doesn't that do it?

Comment: figured selecting "yes" would have been enough.  guarantee there's a bunch of newbies like me who approved comments that way, only to remain unapproved, lol.  oh well, thanks again!